# More than one user is token cache AzureAD

Tags: swift, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am facing below error while logging in to my application. It was working fine until this evening when, all of a sudden, I am getting this error:

```
Error with code: AD_ERROR_CACHE_MULTIPLE_USERS 

Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details: The token cache
 store for this resource contains more than one user.

Inner error details: Error Domain=ADAuthenticationErrorDomain Code=300 "(null)"
 UserInfo={MSIDErrorDescriptionKey=The token cache store for this resource 
 contains more than one user., MSIDCorrelationIdKey=someKey}, mrrt=NO, 
 status=AD_FAILED, item=(null), correlationId= someKey, authority=(null))
```

I have the Authenticator App installed on my device, and I have removed the user account from the app, but I am still facing the same error.

Is there any way I can get around this error? I tried checking Google, but I am not getting any clear solutions for this (or why this happens).

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/issues/1356) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466342/adal-mac-returns-300-ad-error-cache-multiple-users-error). You should also look at migrating to MSAL if you are still using ADAL.  The problem is with data in the keychain, so simply removing your app won't help.

Comment: You should be able to use the [`ADKeychainTokenCache`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ADAL/2.5.1/Classes/ADKeychainTokenCache.html) object to remove all identities for your client to recover.

Comment: @Paulw it seems like when user is logged into multiple devices, this issue shows up. When we removed logged in user from all other devices the issue is gone.

Comment: No, this is a local keychain issue. I experienced this issue when a user's UNC was changed.

Comment: @Paulwa By local keychain you mean ADAL token cache keychain?

Comment: Yes, but that is just an on-device keychain keychain that are shared between your apps on that device. It is not iCloud backed.

Comment: Ok, I am also facing issue clearing  token from keychain cache on logout. I will probably post a new query tomorrow for this issue. Kindly help on that whenever you are free.

Comment: Logout isn't really possible with ADAL. Have you looked at MSAL?  The migration isn't too difficult and it is now Microsoft's recommended framework

Comment: @Paulwa I can look into that, but I still haven't received go from client to make changes. It's not in discussion for now among them. So I have to wait.